# How do i get google sheets to work out when colum D is less than 50% of C and to change colour to amber when this happens

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

How do i get google sheets to work out when colum D is less than 50% of C and to change colour to amber when this happens

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wkIg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting with custom formula to set the condition for a range.

From menu `Format -> Conditional formatting`, set these options and enter `=IF($D1<$C1/2,TRUE)` as custom formula. Also, pick your desired color from `Formatting Style -> Text Color` option.

[image]

Sample data:

[image]

References:

[Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)